# strange template parameter syntax

Tags: c++, templates

```
template<typename Tag, typename Tag::type M>
struct Rob { 
  friend typename Tag::type get(Tag) {
    return M;
  }
};
```

I pick up this code from Johannes Schaub's blog, I have never seen before the syntax used for the 2nd template parameters. what `"Tag::type M"` mean ?

Comment: It means `Tag` has a `typedef`.

Comment: you mean "type" ? but what M stand for?

Comment: M is just the name you give to your templated type. This is equivalent to `<typename MyFirstType, typename MyFirstType::type MySecondType>`

Comment: Could you give us a link to this blog?

Comment: http://bloglitb.blogspot.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have non-type template parameters as long as they are compile-time constants. That is, you can have something like

```
template <int M> ...
```

Now, it may be reasonable to have the type of the non-type template argument depend on a nested type of another template argument:

```
template <typename T, typename T::type M> ...
```

The part `typename T::type` states that `type` is a type and the template argument specified is of this type. A more concrete example would be

```
template <typename T, typename T::size_type S> ...
```

when instantiated with a container type, `S` would be a constant of the container's `size_type`.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, it means that the typename `Tag` defines itself a typename, referred to as `Tag::type`. A class can act as a namespace if you define types (or static variables / functions) inside it, and that's why you use `::` here as you would if you had a namespace.

Your example is equivalent to

```
<typename MyFirstType, typename MyFirstType::type MySecondType>
```

Comment: If M is a type, what does return M mean? It's actually a constant whose type is given by the (typename) Tag::type

Comment: @rici If it was a constant, putting `typename` in front of it would cause a compilation error. Can you show me a working example?

Comment: Actually I just saw the full example from the next post, I didn't even know that was possible (getting private members and stuff)

Comment: The getting private member thing is much wierder than my example. But there you go: C++ has lots of odd little corners.